# nohup starting sql and logging

Tags: sql, oracle, putty

I am new to nohup command but I'm not quite understanding it.
I have an sql script called update_item_loc.sql i'm calling it with putty

I have done the following command up until now

```
login as: **username**  
sprusr13@servername.server.com's password:**xx**

username@servername:~> cd  /fs01/app/rms04/external/scripts
username@servername:/fs01/app/rms04/external/scripts> sqlplus $UP

SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on Fri Jan 27 16:16:50 2012    Copyright (c) 1982, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 
- 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

userDB@DBserver>
```

so the next command would be

```
userDB@DBserver>nohup update_item_loc.sql > /fs01/app/rms04/external/logs/update_item_loc.log &
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um, no.

nohup is not a sqlplus command.  You can use nohup at the shell prompt, to execute a binary or shell script.

So, if you have test.sql that looks like this:

```
select * from dual;
exit
```

and you run it from a shell script, run_test.sh that looks like this:

```
export ORACLE_SID=mysid
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
. oraenv
sqlplus myuser/mypass@$ORACLE_SID @test.sql
```

then you should be able to nohup it with:

```
 $ nohup run_test.sh &
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want to do is to avoid that the connection finishes because of no activity, you can change the putty connection settings:

- Seconds between keepalives to a number greater than 0, I set it to 360sec
- Mark the Enable TCP Keep Alives option